# PHP Upload form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

I just recently set up a working Upload form submission. It was tested and the files and content was going perfectly, straight to my email.

However, I tested it again the other day and it seemed to have stoped working, the email is going through but no data is coming across, the email is just plain blank. I don't understand why this is suddenly happening, or have I deleted something in my code on accident ?

Code (**PHP**):

```
    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
       if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
           $secret = 'My google recaptcha code';
        //get verify response data
           $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
           $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
        $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
        $videolink = !empty($_POST['videolink'])?$_POST['videolink']:'';
           $file = !empty($_POST['sfile'])?$_POST['sfile']:'';
           $fname = $_FILES['sfile']['name'];
        $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';

            $mailto = "Email goes here";
            $subject = 'Upload form submission';
            $htmlContent = "<html>
                <h1>Upload Submission Details:</h1>
                <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
                <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
                   <p><b>Video link: </b>".$videolink."</p>
                   <p><b>File: </b>".$fname."</p>
                <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p></html>
            ";

           $uploaddir = 'tmp';
           @mkdir($uploaddir,0777);
           $name = $_FILES['sfile']['name'];
           $name=$uploaddir."/".$name;
           //$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
           //$tmp_path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sfile']['tmp_name'],$name)) {

       $file_size = filesize($name);
       $handle = fopen($name, "r");
       $mycontent = fread($handle, $file_size);
       fclose($handle);
       $mycontent = chunk_split(base64_encode($mycontent));
       unlink($name);
       //chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["sfile"]["tmp_name"])));
       //chunk_split(base64_encode($mycontent));
       // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
       $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
       $filename = basename($_FILES['sfile']['name']);

   // header
   $header = "From: \"FS Upload submission\" <\"Upload@submissions.com\">\r\n";
   $header .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

   // message & attachment
   $nmessage = "--".$uid."\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
   $nmessage .= $htmlContent."\r\n\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
   $nmessage .= $mycontent."\r\n\r\n";
   $nmessage .= "--".$uid."--";
      }
    if($responseData->success):
   if (mail($mailto, $subject, $nmessage, $header))  {
           $succMsg = 'Mail request has submitted successfully.'; // or use booleans here
         } else {
           echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
         }
            $name = '';
            $email = '';
            $videolink = '';
               $file = '';
            $message = '';
           else:
               $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
           endif;
       else:
           $errMsg = 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA form.';
       endif;
   else:
       $errMsg = '';
       $succMsg = '';
    $name = '';
    $email = '';
       $videolink = '';
       $file = '';
    $message = '';
   endif;
   ?>
```

Code (**HTML & PHP**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/php; charset=UTF-8" />
      <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
   </head>
   <body>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method=POST id=uploadform autocomplete=off>
               <div class=top-row>
                  <div class=field-wrap>
                  <!-- Users name -->
                     <input id="sender" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:''; ?>" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class=field-wrap>
                  <!-- Users email -->
                     <input id=senderEmail type="email" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:''; ?>" placeholder="Email@domain.com" name="email" required>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class=top-row>
                  <div class=field-wrap>
                  <!-- Users link -->
                     <input id="sender" type="text" value="<?php echo !empty($videolink)?$videolink:''; ?>" placeholder="Video Link" name="videolink">
                  </div>
                  <div class=field-wrap>
                  <!-- Users file -->
                     <input id="file" type="file" value="<?php echo !empty($file)?$file:''; ?>" name="sfile">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <textarea id=message type="text" placeholder=Description name=message spellcheck="true" required><?php echo !empty($message)?$message:''; ?></textarea>
               <!-- Recaptcha -->
               <center>
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My Google recaptcha code"></div>
               </center>
               <!-- Error messages -->
               <?php if(!empty($errMsg)): ?>
               <div class="errMsg"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></div>
               <?php endif; ?>
               <?php if(!empty($succMsg)): ?>
               <div class="succMsg"><?php echo $succMsg; ?></div>
               <?php endif; ?>
               <center><input type=submit name=submit class="button button-block" value="SUBMIT"/></center>
               </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you enough free space on your webserver disk?

Comment: Yeh, Because the contact submission is working.